# Writing a two variable function$ f(x,t)$ in terms of Dirac-Delta $δ(x)$ function and a function $P(t)$?

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, structural-beam

How to write a two variable function $f(x,t)$  in terms of Dirac-Delta $\delta(x)$ function and a function $P(t)$?

**For example;**

I read something in a book. You can find the following picture.

But I don' t understand the logic behind this. Could you explain it?

[image]

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3272979/11127

Answer (score 0):

Dirac delta distributions only make sense in an integral. For example, one could want the total work done by the force:

$$W=\int_1^2\boldsymbol{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol{r}$$

In this case, that would mean that all the force is acting on a single point. An integral over a single point gives $0$ ($\int_1^1 = 0$). But since we do want the force to act on the object and do work, we don't want this. In order to have a finite integral value one need to "infinitely concentrate" the force on that point. Thus, the delta dirac distribution.